# How to properly use an expression in a scale function in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, expression, scale, symbols

I am plotting some results with ggplot2. The data are organized in data frame structured like this:

```
   category  comparison    value
1  A         deltaXT/FT    6807
2  B         deltaXT/FT    11894
3  C         deltaXT/FT    1215
4  D         deltaXT/FT    42862
5  E         deltaXT/FT    34313
...
```

There are 4 comparisons in total, each subdivided into the categories A-E, in the same data frame (the plot looks like [this](http://seq.boku.ac.at/websafe/ws/a46e82db/stack.png)). **My aim is to substitute "deltaXT/FT" with "ΔXT/FT"**, using the greek symbol for Delta.

In the plot I'm using the "comparison" column to define the colour of the bars, like this:

```
ggplot(data=vars, aes(x=category, y=value, fill=comparison)) + 
...
scale_fill_manual(values=c("deltaXT/FT"="#6FA9BC"), ...)
```

Basically, everything works just fine while I use "deltaXT/FT" in `scale_fill_manual` and in the original data frame. If I try to use `expression(Delta * "XT/FT")="#6FA9BC", ...)` I get this error:

```
Error: unexpected '=' in:
...
scale_fill_manual(values=c(expression(Delta * "XT/FT"))="
```

The issue seems to be with `scale_fill_manual()`: the `expression()` couldn't be used as key in there. I read other threads here in StackOverflow where people got suggested to use `bquote(expression()=value)` but the error didn't change when using it.

Any suggestion on how to get past this problem and have a nice ΔXT/FT name in the legend?

EDIT: copy-pasting the Δ character into the Rscript where needed works, but I'm more interested in if the `expression()` can be used as a key in such situation in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just change the label associated with each `comparison`, not the value that's mapping it.

```
... +
scale_color_manual(values = c("deltaXT/FT" = "#6FA9BC"), 
                   labels = c("deltaXT/FT" = expression(Delta * "XT/FT")))
```

Or, in a complete plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=category, y=value, color=comparison)) + 
  geom_point(size = 5) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("deltaXT/FT"="#6FA9BC"), 
                     labels = expression(Delta * "XT/FT"))
```

[image]

Data:

```
df <- read.table(text = ' category  comparison    value
1  A         deltaXT/FT    6807
                 2  B         deltaXT/FT    11894
                 3  C         deltaXT/FT    1215
                 4  D         deltaXT/FT    42862
                 5  E         deltaXT/FT    34313', header = TRUE)
```